# How to move Mail messages from Apple Mail back on to Hotmail server?

Tags: mail.app, email, imac

When I first configured Apple Mail, I mistakenly opted not to keep a copy of mail on the Hotmail server. I've now changed that, but would like to move Inbox items that are on Apple Mail back on to the Hotmail server.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup a second account in Mail for your Hotmail account. This time choose Exchange IMAP for the protocol, not POP3. (Use the server settings here: http://www.sirslur.com/2010/09/01/hotmail-has-imap-and-works-on-iphone/)
2. Drag your messages from your previous Hotmail account to your new IMAP-enabled Hotmail account.
3. Grab coffee and wait.

Sometimes messages will fail to sync. Just re-drag them as previously to re-sync them.

Comment: Does Hotmail support IMAP?

Comment: It has Exchange IMAP, which Mail supports. Updated my answer to be more specific, thanks!

Comment: But AFAIK this will only work on mobile devices (iPhone, Android, etc.) - right ??

Answer (score 0):

Unable to create second account as it is has the same email.  "The account "email" already has the host name and user name."

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.